# Win7 scheduled task minute settings?

Tags: windows, windows-7, scheduled-task

I must process a bat file for every minute but win7 scheduled task not allow per minute. Lowest 5 minutes. Can I set scheduled task win7 for per minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it to every minute.
In the advanced properties just edit the "5 minutes" field and change the number.
(It is not only a drop-down selection box, but also an editable field.)
You can even set it to 10 seconds if you really want to.